# Showing p-value on grouped boxplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, p-value

I want to show p-values on above my data (possibly with arcs). My data is below:

```
ID  Blog    Region  Dimension   Score
1   Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -4.75
2   Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -5.69
3   Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -0.27
4   Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -2.76
5   Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -8.24
6   Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -12.51
7   Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -1.28
8   Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus 0.95
9   Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -5.96
10  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -8.81
11  Blog1   PK  Thematic Variation  -8.46
12  Blog1   PK  Thematic Variation  -6.15
13  Blog1   PK  Thematic Variation  -13.98
14  Blog1   PK  Thematic Variation  -16.43
15  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -4.09
16  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -11.06
17  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -9.04
18  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -8.56
19  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -8.13
20  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -14.46
21  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -4.21
22  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -4.96
23  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -5.48
24  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -4.53
25  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  6.31
26  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -11.16
27  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -1.27
28  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -11.49
29  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -0.9
30  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -12.27
31  Blog1   PK  Thematic Variation  6.85
32  Blog1   PK  Thematic Variation  -5.21
33  Blog1   PK  Thematic Variation  -1.06
34  Blog1   PK  Thematic Variation  -2.6
35  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -0.95
36  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -0.82
37  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -7.65
38  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style 0.64
39  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -2.25
40  Blog1   PK  Narrative Style -1.58
41  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -5.73
42  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  0.37
43  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -5.46
44  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  -3.48
45  Blog1   PK  Info. vs. P. Focus  0.88
46  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -2.11
47  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -10.13
48  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -2.08
49  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus -4.33
50  Blog1   PK  Addressee Focus 1.09
51  Blog1   US  Thematic Variation  -4.23
52  Blog1   US  Thematic Variation  -1.46
53  Blog1   US  Thematic Variation  9.37
54  Blog1   US  Thematic Variation  5.84
55  Blog1   US  Narrative Style 8.21
56  Blog1   US  Narrative Style 7.34
57  Blog1   US  Narrative Style 1.83
58  Blog1   US  Narrative Style 14.39
59  Blog1   US  Narrative Style 22.02
60  Blog1   US  Narrative Style 4.83
```

The code is below:

```
get_wraper <- function(width) {
  function(x) {
    lapply(strwrap(x, width = width, simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse="\n")
  }
}
plotgraph <- function(x, y, colour, min, max, incr, p_values)
{
  plot1 <- ggplot(dims_Blog, aes_string(x = x, y = y, fill = colour)) +
    geom_boxplot()+
    labs(color=colour) +
    labs(x="Dimensions", y="Score") +
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0.3, end = 0.6) +
    theme_grey()+
    theme(legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position = c(1, 1)) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = get_wraper(10))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(seq(min,max,incr)), limits = c(min, max))+
    theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())+
    geom_text(data = dims_Blog %>% group_by_(x, colour) %>% summarise_(mean=paste("mean(",y,", na.rm=TRUE)")), aes_string(x=x, y="mean", label="round(mean,3)"), position=position_dodge(width=0.8), size = 3, vjust = -0.5, colour="white")+
    geom_text(data = p_values, aes_string(x="Dimension", y="height", label="val"))
  return(plot1)
}
```

## plot graph

```
plot1 <- plotgraph("Dimension", "Blog1", "Region", -30, 50, 10, p_val1)
plot1
```

## data frame for p-values

```
Dimensions <- c("Info. vs. P. Focus", "Addressee Focus", "Thematic Variation", "Narrative Style")
val <- c("0.184", "0.079", "0.044", "\u003C.0001")
height <- c(48, 48, 48, 48)
p_val1 <-data.frame(Dimensions, val, height)
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how to define geom_text for showing p-values.

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): label, x, y, fill
```

I have tried go through a few similar questions but my limited knowledge did not let me solve the problem. Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you were very close in the original post: the error message says that you need to provide `label, x, y, fill` attributes for every layer. (That is because you defined these attributes in the main `ggplot` call.) The layer that you use for p-values includes three of these aesthetics in the `aes_string(x="Dimensions", y="height", label="val")`. Try adding a constant fill, like:

```
+ geom_text(data = p_values, aes_string(x="Dimensions", y="height", label="val"), fill="black")
```

or you can move the aesthetics definitions out of the main call, if you are not using multiple layers anyway:

```
ggplot(dims_Blog) +
    geom_boxplot(aes_string(x = x, y = y, fill = colour)) +
    ... +
    geom_text(data = p_values, aes_string(x="Dimensions", y="height", label="val"))
```

Secondly, there's a typo - you refer to `Dimension` in the plotting call, but `Dimensions` in creating the p-val dataframe.

I haven't tested this without having the full dataset, though, so something additional might come up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had corrected the typo in my code later on. I will try using a data frame next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `annotate` instead of `geom_text` which takes three separate vectors (?) instead of a data frame. The code is shown below:

```
annotate("text",x=Dimension,y=height,label=val)
Dimension <- c("Info. vs. P. Focus", "Addressee Focus", "Thematic Variation", "Narrative Style")
height <- c(48, 48, 48, 48)
val <- c("p=0.184", "p=0.079", "p=0.044", "p\u003C.0001")
```

This is not a very good solution, but at least it printed the values I wanted it to print. I don't know how to expand these vectors to 8 (as my previous data frames are of this size). That was the problem as well.